# FlyCapture2 and OpenCV, CMake build question

Tags: opencv

Platform: amd_64
Operating System: Ubuntu 8.10

Problem:
The current release of OpenCV (2.1 at time of writing) and libdc1394 doesn't properly interface with the new USB-interface PointGrey High-Res FireFlyMV Color camera.

Does anyone have this camera working with OpenCV on Ubuntu?

Currently, I'm working on writing my own frame-grabber using PointGrey's FlyCapture2 SDK, which works well with the camera. I'd like to interface this with OpenCV, by converting each image I grab into an IplImage object. When I write OpenCV programs, I use CMake. The example code for the FlyCapture2 SDK uses fairly simple makefiles. Does anyone know how I can take the information from the simple FlyCapture2 makefile so I can include the appropriate lines in CMakeLists.txt for my CMake build routine?

Comment: I still have yet to track down the cause of the camera error, as I don't have the time to further describe and investigate the error. I switched to Windows, where PointGrey cameras work much better.

I did, however, figure out how to incorporate both FlyCapture and OpenCV libraries in the same project using CMake. 

Using a CMake file that already works with OpenCV, all that needs adding are the following lines, assuming flycapture is installed in /usr, and with project name [projectname]:

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/flycapture")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( [projectname] flycapture )

Comment: You've answered your own question in terms of the "cmake" tag here... Do you have an answer for the rest of it as well? If not, perhaps remove the CMake tag, so it does not appear under "unanswered" cmake questions...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, DLRdave, I've removed the cmake tag. It really is just an OpenCV question.

Comment: agodbehere, can you tell me how you converted the flycapture image to one openCV can read? I have the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a simple answer (sorry) - but.

Generally you don't want to use cvCaptureCam() for high performance cameras beyond initial tests that they work. Even for standard interfaces like firewire It is very limited in what features of the camera it can control, it doesn't handle threading well and the performance is poor - especially at high data rates.

The more common way is to control the camera with the makers own SDK and output frames in a form (cv::mat/iplimage) that openCV can process. All openCV image types are very flexible in being able to share data with the camera API and specify padding/row striping etc so you should be able to design it so there is no unnecessary copying.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. That's exactly what I ended up doing, but I appreciate your explanation.